# What's the best way to draw something like THIS using Flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

I am trying to create a "radar-like" control within our Flex application.

See the following link for an example (sorry, small image...)
http://www.radware.com/uploadedImages/Products/Management/Insite/Security-Dashboard.jpg

This is my first foray into drawing with Flex.
I would like to draw the main circles of the radar, the radar scanning shape, and circles/balls representing objects within the radar.  These objects need to have the ability to be clicked on or hovered over so the user can get more information.

I'm looking at Sprite's and Shapes, etc. but confused as which to use to create such a control.

Any tips, links or suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of good options in Flex 3

http://www.axiis.org/

http://www.degrafa.org/blog/category/data-visualization/

http://visunetdemos.demos.ibm.com/webdemos/radar/radar.html

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I hadn't seen axiis.  Very interesting.  Degrafa may be the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Before I jump into degrafa, I simply did the following to get the basic radar display drawn.  Any thoughts or feedback on how I did this would be great.

```
            var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var mySprite2:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var mySprite3:Sprite = new Sprite();
            mySprite3.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
            mySprite3.graphics.drawCircle(210, 210, 200);               

            mySprite2.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xA10303, .75);
            mySprite2.graphics.drawCircle(210, 210, 150);


            mySprite.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xA10303, .75);
            mySprite.graphics.drawCircle(210, 210, 75);

            this.rawChildren.addChild(mySprite3);   
            this.rawChildren.addChild(mySprite2);
            this.rawChildren.addChild(mySprite);
```